# How to pass data from detail to master in UISplitViewController for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I want to pass data from detail view controller to master view controller of UISplitViewController for iPad. I have a login view controller as root view before splitView in storyboard. I tried by creating a custom delegate to pass data but it does not work.
Data will pass from didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of DetailViewController. Please let me know where i'm doing wrong. Below is my code -

In MasterViewController.m -

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) DelegateToPassDataInMaster *delegateController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *objects;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
}

- (void) getRowID:(NSString *)_id {
    NSLog(@"Row ID : %@", _id);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.delegateController = [[DelegateToPassDataInMaster alloc] init];
    self.delegateController.delegate = self;

    self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = str;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

In DetailViewController.m -

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "DelegateToPassDataInMaster.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) DelegateToPassDataInMaster *delegateController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *objects;

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.delegateController = [DelegateToPassDataInMaster new];

    self.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *str = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = str;
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *str = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    [self.delegateController getDataFromDelegateFunc:str];
}

@end
```

In DelegateToPassDataInMaster.h -

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol DelegateForPassDataToMasterView;

@interface DelegateToPassDataInMaster : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id <DelegateForPassDataToMasterView> delegate;
-(void) getDataFromDelegateFunc:(NSString *)_id;

@end

#pragma mark -

@protocol DelegateForPassDataToMasterView <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)getRowID:(NSString *)_id;

@end
```

In DelegateToPassDataInMaster.h -

```
#import "DelegateToPassDataInMaster.h"

@implementation DelegateToPassDataInMaster

-(void) getDataFromDelegateFunc:(NSString *)_id {
    [self.delegate getRowID:_id];
}

@end
```

Comment: Hey Nuibb, I think it's because you're not making a real reference to the master controller, you're creating a new object. Want me to expand?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain this elaborately please ? I don't get it actually. What should i do ?

Comment: In my AppDelegate.m, i deleted all the line related to spliteView. Such as- - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 
    return YES;
}

Comment: Yep, I can explain, give me a few minutes

Comment: See my answer here for a simpler solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813442/split-view-controller-how-to-connect-master-view-controller-to-detail-view-cont/33622958#33622958

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when making a delegate you implement the protocol on the detail view & you set the delegate of this protocol to the place you want to do work (e.g, the master view).

In your case, you have done this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) DelegateToPassDataInMaster *delegateController;
```

So your delegate is set up, but now when you assign `delegateController` to something is where you make the mistake.

Here in your master, you have made an object, and set that as the delegate

```
self.delegateController = [[DelegateToPassDataInMaster alloc] init];
self.delegateController.delegate = self;
```

But that has no reference to this in your detail view:

```
self.delegateController = [DelegateToPassDataInMaster new];
```

So, you need to setting self.delegateController to your master view controller. To get the reference, you can use

```
self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
```

inside your master view. I will expand further if you need, but I hope you understand well enough to implement this.

Comment: Does this make sense Nuibb?

Comment: Actually i am not clear about it. Please let me know how to set up self.delegateController in my master view. I deleted "self.delegateController = [[DelegateToPassDataInMaster alloc] init];" in master and added "self.delegateController = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1];" in detail view controller. but it crashes.

Comment: Ok, so you need to import  MasterViewController.h, then do self.delegateController = (MasterViewController*) self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1];

Comment: You do not need: "@property (strong, nonatomic) DelegateToPassDataInMaster *delegateController;" in the master view

Comment: Sorry it's not working. I think i'm doing wrong to set up delegate in master view & can't find out that. I'm sorry for incapable of doing it. Can you please see the whole code from here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/87ogi7rfag7ebsq/DataPassFromDetailToMaster.zip?dl=0

Comment: haha, don't worry, it's learning :P i can have a look soon, i will get back to you

Comment: ok, done Nuibb, i've changed the way it works a bit, hopefully you can see how it works

Comment: Thank you Sir. I'll test and reply asap. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you sir, it's working. I'll post later as comment what i had done wrong before. It will help someone else i think.

Comment: here is the way I was trying to make it happen the first time I answered: http://www.speedyshare.com/qEeRJ/DataPassFromDetailToMaster-3.zip    it's just setting delegate from the detail rather than master :P

Comment: Thank you, for some reason first version of your code does not work for me when integrated in my main project. But second version works well. I don't know why first version works great in your demo but not in my main project. I'll figure it out and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, well if you don't solve it in an hour, repost a new question and link here and we will find :D